# The HTML5 form validation works only if I submit the form?

Tags: jquery, html, forms

I am pretty new to HTML5 and I have the following doubt.

In a page I have this situation:

```
<div id="inserimentoVariazioneAnticipo" class="row">
    <div class="col-md-5">
        <p style="line-height: 200%;">Inserire la variazione dell'anticipo:</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-7">
        <input id="variazioneAnticipo" class="rightAlligned form-control" style="width:50%" type="text" type="number" step="0.01" />
    </div>
</div>

<button id="confermaAnnullaTrasmissione" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">
    Conferma
</button>
```

So as you can see I have an `input` tag having `type="number" step="0.01"` set because it has to take a decimal number.

As you can see I don't have `<form>` tag because I don't have to submit the form but I have to perform a jQuery function when the `confermaAnnullaTrasmissione` button is clicked.

The problem is that, doing it this way, seems to me that the HTML5 type validation doesn't work because I can insert any kind of value inside my input tag. Is it or am I missing something? The validation works only if the form is submitted?

How can I solve this issue and validate my input without submitting any form?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two things:

First, remove `type="text"` from your input. You are mixing `type="text"` and `type="number"`.

Second, you can validate all forms or individual form-elements with HTML5 Validation API.

```
 document.getElementById('variazioneAnticipo').checkValidity();
```

That line returns if the validation is successful or not.

See this interesting article about the validation API:

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/forms/constraintvalidation

Answer (score -2):

Add jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js file.

You can Fire jquery function like this:

```
$.validator.unobtrusive.parse("#frmcreateCountry");

$("#formid").on("submit",function(){

  if($(this).valid())
   {
     // server code here 
       }



       });
```